# for loop to jstl forEach

Tags: java, jstl

How to convert below `for` loop to a `jstl` `foreach`:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<=21; i+=3){
  // print foo
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
<c:forEach varStatus="loop" begin="0" end="21">
  // display foo
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Acoording to [jstl](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) you should try:

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="21" step="3" varStatus="loop">
    <c:out value="${loop.count}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: No, you can have just one var. But you can have multiple loops to get multiple variables. Take a look at : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html

Answer (score 3):

you can use jstl step attribute

```
<c:forEach varStatus="loop" begin="0" end="21" step="3">
  // display foo
</c:forEach>
```

[JSTL tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm)

Answer (score -1):

```
`<c:forEach
items="<object>"
begin="<int>"
end="<int>"
step="<int>"
var="<string>"
varStatus="<string>">
</c:forEach>`
```

**items** --  Collection of items to iterate in the loop

**begin**  --  Begin index of the iteration. Iteration begins at the value mentioned in this attribute value. (if items specified) First item has index of 0.In your case begin="0"

**end**  --  End index of the iteration. Iteration stops at the value mentioned in this attribute value (inclusive). (if items specified).In your case begin="49".

**step**  --  Step value for the iteration specified in this attribute.In your case step="3".

**var**  --  Name of the scoped variable which holds the current item in the iteration. This variable’s type depends on the items in the iteration and has nested visibility.

**varStatus**  --   Name of the scoped variable which holds the loop status of the current iteration. This variable is of type javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagStatus and has nested visibility.

**to increment by 3 -->** step="3"

**end loop on 49 -->** end="49"

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333079/jstl-loop-counter-3-increment/39334822#39334822)

Answer (score -2):

Also if you want to use the value itself, you can use the 'current' attribute.

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="2" varStatus="position">
   ${position.current}
</c:forEach>
```

this will give:

0
1
2

this is usefull when you are working with arrays which are zero-based.