# JSTL LOOP - counter +=3 Increment

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have to iterate a collections in JSTL, but I would like the index to be incremented +3 each loop, something like

```
for (int i=0; i<50; i+=3) {
}
```

but in JSTL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `<c:forEach/>` tag which exist as an alternative for `while`, `do-while` and for Loop in `jstl` via `scriptlet`

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="50" step="3" >
        <c:out value="${i}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

`begin` for initialization, `end` for termination and `step` for increment

Answer (score 1):

```
`<c:forEach
items="<object>"
begin="<int>"
end="<int>"
step="<int>"
var="<string>"
varStatus="<string>">
</c:forEach>`
```

**items** --  Collection of items to iterate in the loop

**begin**  --  Begin index of the iteration. Iteration begins at the value mentioned in this attribute value. (if items specified) First item has index of 0.In your case begin="0"

**end**  --  End index of the iteration. Iteration stops at the value mentioned in this attribute value (inclusive). (if items specified).In your case begin="49".

**step**  --  Step value for the iteration specified in this attribute.In your case step="3".

**var**  --  Name of the scoped variable which holds the current item in the iteration. This variable’s type depends on the items in the iteration and has nested visibility.

**varStatus**  --   Name of the scoped variable which holds the loop status of the current iteration. This variable is of type javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagStatus and has nested visibility.

**to increment by 3 -->** step="3"

**end loop on 49 -->** end="49"